# RegEx that will make sure that the first character after a space in a string is a `#`

Tags: regex

Trying to build a regex to verify a string that would look something like this

`#tag #tag2 #tag3` and not like this `#tag1 tag2 tag3`

I need a regex that will make sure that the first character after a space in the string is a `#`.

I have the check to make sure the first character is a `#` but that is as far as I have been able to get on this.

```
pattern: /^\#/
```

Comment: Try: `^#[^#\s]*(?:\s#[^#\s]*)*$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```bash
^#[^#\s]*(?:\s#[^#\s]*)*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wWsOVm/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^`: Start
- `#`: Match a `#`
- `[^#\s]*`: Match 0 or more of any characters that are not `#` and not a whitespace
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `\s`: Match a whitespace
  - `#`: Match a `#`
  - `[^#\s]*`: Match 0 or more of any characters that are not `#` and not a whitespace
- `)*`: End non-capture group
- `$`: End